# text editor in textarea SLOW - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm implementing a simple ( not rich ) text editor in html using a fixed size ( doesn't automatically grow ) textarea. I have made a pagination system which splits the text to fit that textarea. With relativelay large texts ( 20 pages = 20 textareas ) the function takes about 100ms in total for those 20 pages ( less if there is less text ). the logic is like this:

```
function paginate() {
    clienth = textarea.clientheight;
    while (maxTextSize>minTextSize+1) {
        textarea.value = text;
        // a binary subdivision algorithm which runs in logarithmic time
        if (textarea.scrollheight>clienth) {
            text = newsmallertext;
        } else {
          text = newbiggertext;
        }
        maxTextSize = newvalue1;
        minTextSize = newvalue2;
    }
}
```

so for about 14 KB of text ( 19pages ), the function gets called 187 times ( 10 times per page ) with a time of about 100ms for firefox, ~60ms for chrome and opera and about 200ms for IE. Of those 100ms, about 40ms are spent for assigning the text to the textarea ( .value = blabla ) and the rest 60 for checking if the scrollheight is bigger than clientheight. So, 99% of the time is spent there.

That doesn't SEEM a lot but it is. Why ? Because I need to call that function EVERY TIME a user types ( presses a key ) in the textarea in order to apply the new text accordingly. The user may type a letter, backspace, delete, hit enter and so on and so forth. So for each keydown i call the paginate function again  to calculate the new text that fits the textarea. Which makes typing VERY SLOW since for each pressed key there is a delay of 100ms.

So I was wondering if there is an optimization for assigning the text to the textarea or checking scrollheight, or a TOTALLY different way for this.

Thank you in advance for all suggestions.

please do not suggest to make the textarea automatically grow, it's NOT in the requirements.

edit: made the while() loop more clear about what it does.

Comment: For a first glance, this shouldn't be slow because as long as `doesnt_fit` returns false, your whole algorithm will not be executed, and most of the key press should not make it to true - you'll need 100 key presses on a 100 characters long area. How is your `doesnt_fit` implemented? And is it possible to make some of your algorithm non-blocking?

Comment: the function gets called about 10 times for each page. so for 19 pages it's called 187 times.

in the beginning let's say the text chunk is 10KB. so the scrollheight is bigger. I cut the textchunk in half...5k it's still bigger...again in half..after some steps it becomes smaller...then i make it bigger again until MinTextSize + 1 = MaxTextSize ( that is with minsize it fits but with max it doesnt. So it basically it is a binary division algorithm which works in logarithmic time. It cannot be any faster.

it's actually while(MaxTextSize>MinTextChunkSize+1)

Comment: Making it no blocking would be possible with a setimeout(function,0) BUT that way the user could press another key before the pagination ending and thus the textarea being redrawn(refilled) after the user has pressed another key. It would be messy

Comment: I'm a little lost here. Are you saying that the _initial data_ is lagging your UI, or that you're redoing pagination process on _every_ input?

Comment: @Passerby let's take as an assumption that the initial data is null. The moment i start typing, i do the pagination...which is fast if the data is not large, for example if the text is under 800Bytes, it fits in the textarea, the pagination function takes about 1 ms. But if i continue typing and as the data grows to 14KB...that's about 20 pages..and for 20 pages it takes 100 ms to paginate it. So for every keystroke ( when the data is 14KB ) i get a 100ms pagination time, which lags the UI. imagine what would happen at 50KB or 100KB text

Comment: Do you mean you're redoing the **whole** pagination process on _every_ input? I.e. 1 byte -> 1 page, ... 1k -> split into 2 pages, ... 1.5k -> split into 3 pages? I was assuming it will only be triggered when the cursor reaches "next page", i.e. 1 byte -> 1 page, ... 801 bytes -> grow one more page, ... 1601 bytes -> grow one more page.

Comment: yes exactly, the pagination is triggered on every input because you never know if a typed character will make the text larger than the textarea ( the cursor may be in the middle of the textarea ) and thus there will be a need for repaginating.

Comment: also you never know how much data you need to fill the textarea, it may be 20 bytes ( for example it's full of only newline characters ), or around 1KB if you fill all the lines with normal chars..

Comment: So you're re-splitting the whole text (whatever size it is) on every input. I think this logic is something you may want to improve. Is it possible for your algorithm to focus on the "current page"? I.e. when text are long, take one page off the textarea, into cache, and only fetch it when necessary (e.g. backspace).

Comment: hm I'm not sure I understood what you suggested. The user can go from one page to the other ( like in ms word ). What i was thinking is to somehow paginate only the current text + some before + some after it ( that is 3 pages ) and when he changes page, paginate next chunk of 3 pages or previous chunk of 3 pages.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're playing with DOM with UI in pagination process, that can't be very fast. I think your 3-pages-module is way better than serving all pages. If some text is too "far away", put it in cache (some variable).

Comment: yes, however if the user ( through a button ) wants to go to page 19 from page 2 then i will have to paginate the whole thing

Comment: Yes, but that scenario is rare -- at least not as common as "typing text from page 1 to page 2". And I think it's worth to pay ~100ms+ "long jump" delay for smooth typing.

Comment: Also, can you save "paged" text in DOM? E.g. one "page" DIV per page text, so that you can have random access and a controllable UI.

Comment: yes 100ms for a long jump is fine. i will try it do it this way, with partial pagination close to the current page.
As for save paged text in DOM not possible, because if the current text has changed, so will have to change the "long jump" page

Comment: @MirrorMirror did you find a solution? I am having the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065048/fast-alternatives-for-element-clientheight-and-element-offsetheight

Comment: @Amin if I remember correctly I did it partial. Not all text at the same time, just the current page +-1

Comment: Thanks! In my case there is a single element, so probably I cannot do anything.